# PostgreSQL time formatting

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to format timestamp to the following format in PostgreSQL?

```
2019-10-14T16:16:47.026Z
```

Comment: [to_char()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: I tried that but I can't get time with that Z at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
select to_char(col, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS.MSTZ')
```

Of course, the timezone depends on the timezone for the value.

Comment: it gives "syntax error" for current situation. I need the same solution, please.

Comment: cursor.execute("SELECT to_char(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS.MSTZ),temperature FROM conditions WHERE time > NOW() - interval '1000 days';")